# Adding spatial clustering data in Map by R

Tags: dictionary, cluster-analysis

I have the results for spatial clustering, in this results I have the id for some cities in USA. I would like to show this clustering results on a nice map. Is this feasible in R?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is feasible.

You need to map the city ids to geographical data, then visualize it.

With the extensive drawing capabilities of R, this is not very hard; there are several R packages that will do the heavy lifting, and tutorials to guide you. Just pick whatever package you prefer.

We cannot give you a complete source, of course, because we don't know what kind of ids you have. For example many people use zip codes, others use FIPS ids, etc.

Comment: I just have the name of coounty in a state.